# Using parfor in Matlab to read and modify a file

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I have a code where I need to read and modify a certain file several times. Since the code takes a lot of time, I tried to use `parfor` to accelerate it.

```
parfor i=1:n_par

    tmp= fullfile('/path',sprintf('code%d',i),'utchem >> output');
    %% MATLABPOOL will synchronise the path and current directory between client and workers       
    tmpdir=fullfile('/path',sprintf('code%d',i));
    cd(tmpdir);

    %% INPUT is the file from which each time I read and modify
    A = regexp(fileread('INPUT'), '\n', 'split');

    A{226} = sprintf('%g  %g  %g', para(i,1), para(i,2), para(i,3));
    A{230} = sprintf('%g  %g  %g', para(i,4), para(i,5), para(i,6));
    A{234} = sprintf('%g  %g  %g', para(i,7), para(i,8), para(i,9));
    %% para is a variable already defined before the parfor loop 

    %% write the cell into the textfile;
    fid = fopen('INPUT', 'w');
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', A{:});
    fclose(fid);

    %% call the code
    system(tmp);

    %% copy and rename file
    test=['test',num2str(i),'.txt'];
    %% rename a file
    copyfile('CORE-S.HIST02', test);  

    hist=textread(test, '%s','delimiter', '\n');
end;
```

The solution that I implemented consists of making copies of the same file `'INPUT'` in each folder `code_i` as the number of needed times `'n_para'`.

Although this helped to improve the time issue, the problem is that each time I run the simulation I have to create those files and in my case I need to do this a huge number of times. I was wondering if someone has a better idea to overcome this issue?

Comment: It's difficult to understand the problem without seeing actual code. I would try to read only the original and write to copies in each worker.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I will include the code in the original post to make myself clear.